# Flutter: What's the way to save a list globally, so state is maintained after navigating around my app?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, save, state

I basically have a to-do styled list, where users can create list items and it shows in a list on the screen. When I navigate backwards to my main menu and return, the list is not saved. I have saved the lists sate like this:

```
class CustomExScreenState extends State<CustomExScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Exerciselist> items = new List<Exerciselist>();
  GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> animatedListKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  AnimationController emptyListController;
```

Would I need to replicate this code for each 'screen' I can navigate to? Is the a better/easier way? Apologies if the question isn't clear, I am new to programming and am a bit lost. If someone can give me a point in the right direction that would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways basically:

1. use provider package: you create a `ChangeNotifier` and put your list there, then you provide this `ChangeNotifier` in your widget tree above all widgets that should access it, then you can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to access the list from all priviliged widgets ( click [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-example-tab-) for an example of using this package)
2. (less elegant): you can define the list as a global variable in a module (file) outside of any class, and import it to any other file and use it

Comment: Thanks for guidance! Will play around with both methods.

Comment: @SiimmKahn please mark as correct if it answers your question